# How can I terminate a loop started in a BEGIN block?

Tags: progress-bar, splash-screen, raku

I would like to show a progress bar while the application is loading/initializing.

This code doesn't work, but should give you an idea of what
I'm trying to accomplish.

```
my Bool $done-compiling = False;
BEGIN {
    start repeat {
        print '*';
        sleep 0.33;
    } until $done-compiling;
};

INIT {
    $done-compiling = True;
};
```

Is there an event triggered that I could respond to in the BEGIN block?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the code is ok.  And if you simulate loading, you'll see a progress bar of *'s:

```
my Bool $done-compiling;
BEGIN {
    start repeat {
        print '*';
        sleep 0.33;
    } until $done-compiling;
}

BEGIN sleep 3; # simulate compilation / loading

INIT $done-compiling = True;
```

Setting the flag in the `INIT` block should be enough!  I guess you could consider execution of the `INIT` block to be the event you're looking for?

Comment: Note that output is buffered by default, so the printing of `*`s will likely not appear in a timely fashion; You may want to add this as the first line of the BEGIN block:

    BEGIN {
        $*OUT.out-buffer = False;

If you want, you can re-enable the buffering after you're done with BEGIN/INIT time work.

Comment: Using Welcome to Rakudo™ v2022.07.
Implementing the Raku® Programming Language v6.d.
Built on MoarVM version 2022.07. 
on a macos Monterey 12.5

When I add these lines to your program:

`prompt "?? ";
say "Done.";`

I get the following output: (I typed `hello world` at the prompt):

`**********?? *****h*e*ll*o*****wo*r*ld********
Done.`


The progress bar continues going after the program starts executing.

Comment: @Coke: if $*OUT.t, pretty sure it's unbuffered.  It was for me, at least.

Comment: @JimBollinger Ah yes, my bad.  The `INIT` would set the flag to `True`, and then regular execution starts.  And that's at line 1, with the flag being reset to `False`.  Remove `= False` (like I just did in the example) and it should work as you intend. :-)

Answer (score 7):

Liz has provided a solution in terms of the code you'd written, fixing the bug that was in your original.

Here's a simpler version:

```
BEGIN start repeat { print '*'; sleep 0.33 } until INIT True
```

(You might be thinking `INIT True` is some special feature but it just falls out naturally from how phasers that return a value work.)

Answer (score 2):

You've already gotten two answers that work.  But both of them rely on using variables across different threads, which always makes me a bit nervous.  Given that we need multiple threads here, I'd probably turn to one of Raku's helpful concurrency primitives.  Here's a very minor change to the accepted answer that uses a `Promise`:

```raku
my Promise $done-compiling;
BEGIN {
    $done-compiling .= new;
    start repeat {
        print '*';
        sleep 0.33;
    } until $done-compiling ~~ Kept;
}

BEGIN sleep 3; # simulate compilation / loading

INIT $done-compiling.keep;
```

Comment: Thanks - not only is this elegant, but I learned more about Promises!

Comment: @codesections "both of them rely on using variables across different threads" I was thinking the `INIT` phaser would not -- could not -- yield a (non `Nil`) value until the enclosing compunit's run-phase had begun (and presumed the code would be in the main/`MAIN` compunit). I had even done a variety of tests to try and disprove what I thought to no avail. But I didn't check the compiler's code. Presumably you did, or you know something I don't know. Anyhoo, it'll prolly be best for later readers if you explain in a comment below my answer rather than here. (And then I'll delete this comment.)

Comment: @raiph I'm actually not sure about the point you raised.  It *might* be entirely safe, for the reason you say.  But I know that multiple threads are involved (see https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/9/J1d3TT6G4JLGoRKEotSA1sUShWqE4sVJBRSvEI8jV0cVaoTgnNbVAwUDP2FihVqE0ryQzR8HTzzMEqk4pMy@zxAquXMlaIaSoNFWhlosLajRYt7E1FxeKqf//AwA ).  And, as I said, sharing data across threads without a concurrency safe  wrapper makes me nervous -- that is, even if it's fine, I'd rather not have the distraction of proving that to myself.

Comment: Are you unsure what `INIT` is supposed to do? I'm presuming it's a phaser that triggers ASAP during the run-phase aka running the program after all compilation units within the program have finished their compile-phases. Or whether Rakudo or my brain has bugs? I mentioned I'd tested my solution to clarify I'd checked the latter. I am as confident as I can ever get that it would work and still am. It would imo be *insane* if it did not. But when I'm that confident my instinctual reaction is to try disprove what I'm thinking in case either Rakudo or my brain are buggy. What are you unsure about?

Comment: See also https://tio.run/##bY7BCoJAFEX3fsVFAqFFBEKLXBlJuZEof2CChw7Yc3gzEhF@@5QTiIv259xzDUm3896qFxLXEoz0jagHtIUMzJqbJIuisiprBCa/5Rc8W2Is6Ts1mi1cP0mTcChOZQXrlDgIGVIO7zCwWtfna5EfM9iOyGC7SVOMGNjpDiHz42LN2u1nPM5Qy0AY5@lgp99UoP9fX/refwA

Comment: I guess I'm utterly confused by "both of them rely on using variables across different threads". I see one in Liz's answer but not mine. I thought perhaps you were talking about some bug in Rakudo involving a variable it uses, perhaps as part of some parallel pipeline compunit compilation process, that is so bad that Rakudo begins running programs before it's finished compiling them. So that there's not only an overlap between compile-time and run-time (which is fair enough) but between compile-phase and run-phase. That would be a monstrous bug. But I reasoned it must be what you meant. Is it?

Comment: @raiph No, I'm not describing any Rakudo bug (definitely not a monstrous one).  My thought process was a lot more simplistic: ① `start` runs code concurrently; ② both solutions use `start` (and, as shown by both tio.run examples, actually do run multiple threads); ③ both solutions cause something to happen in one thread (ending the loop) based on a value produced in the other thread; ④ that _might_ be guaranteed to be threadsafe, but it's a sort of data-sharing-across-threads that makes me nervous.  Does that make more sense?

Comment: @codesections It makes Marvin the Android sense.  "in one thread (ending the loop) based on a value produced in the other thread." The producing code/value in my solution is just `True`. "that *might* be guaranteed to be threadsafe" If `True` isn't guaranteed thread safe then nothing is! Does that make sense?  FYI Liz's and your solution data races -- will `.keep` beat `~~ Kept`? If `.keep` loses there'll be an extra `*` displayed after the program begins to run. Not a big deal, but wanting to win that race which I saw in Liz's is what drove me to my solution -- afaik it always wins it.